# Drop down menu on click on variable id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a grid of images. I want a drop down to appear on whatever image is clicked. The code I have allows for a specific id, rather than any id. The code I have works fine, but it's id specific.

CSS:

```
.wide { width:50px; }
.high { height:50px; }
table { 
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
td {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
td img {
    display:block;
}
.messagepop {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #999999;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left:2px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
    width:50px;
    z-index:50;
    font-family:Tahoma;
}
.messagepop p, .messagepop.div{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
    line-height:1.3em;
    display:inline;
}
.close {
    color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td class="wide high">
    <div class="messagepop pop" id="x1y1pop">
        <p>dfkj</p>
        <p>alksdjh</p>
        <p class="close">Cancel</p>
    </div>

    <img alt="test" src="images/gray.jpg" class="wide high" id="x1y1" />
</td>
```

JQuery:

```
function deselect(e) {
    $('#x1y2pop').slideFadeToggle(function () {
        e.removeClass('selected');
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('#x1y2').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            deselect($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $('#x1y2pop').slideFadeToggle();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('.close').on('click', function () {
        deselect($('#x1y2'));
        return false;
    });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function (easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({
        opacity: 'toggle',
        height: 'toggle'
    }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

I need `$('#x1y2pop').slideFadeToggle` and `$('#x1y2').on` and `$('#x1y2pop').slideFadeToggle();` and `deselect($('#x1y2'));` to be able to accept variables rather than static ids. Like

```
$(selector).on('click', function(){
```

where `selector` is a variable. Is this possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, as you can pass any string you want, but I think you're thinking about this the wrong way. Target your elements by class instead of id. What exactly are you trying to accomplish, because I think you have created an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Each image has an x and a y id so we know which image has been clicked, and for other programming behind the scenes including image switching. I know I can get the id of an image that's been clicked, I just don't know enough about JQuery to know how to use that in this code. If I do elements by class, then the menu will open over every image on the page. I only want the image clicked on to get the menu.

Comment: That's why you use a class to target, don't put it on every image, just the ones you want to have the behavior on, or better yet, on a common parent element if possible.

Comment: I need a menu to pop up for each image so a user can select an action to perform based on which image `src` is being shown at the time. So if user clicks `img id="x1y1" src="green.jpg"`, the code can see the `src` of the image and change it to another image based on that. I need one of these menus for each and every image currently displayed in the table. If I put `class="blah"` on each image, then if I click one image, a menu will pop up over all the `blah`s on the page.

Comment: No, only the one you clicked on will popup. See my answer, it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you can fix this problem best by targeting classes instead of IDs. Additionally, you can use jQuery's [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to target the related `<div>`.

Something like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.canToggle img').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            deselect($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            $(this).prev(".messagepop.pop").slideFadeToggle();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('.close').on('click', (function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var pop = $(this).closest(".messagepop.pop");
        pop.slideFadeToggle(function() {
            pop.next("img").removeClass('selected');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="canToggle">
    <tr>
        <td class="wide high">
            <div class="messagepop pop" id="x1y1pop">
                <p>dfkj</p>
                <p>alksdjh</p>
                <p class="close">Cancel</p>
            </div>

            <img alt="test" src="images/gray.jpg" class="wide high" id="x1y1" />
        </td>
        <td class="wide high">
            <div class="messagepop pop" id="x1y2pop">
                <p>dfkj</p>
                <p>alksdjh</p>
                <p class="close">Cancel</p>
            </div>

            <img alt="test" src="images/gray.jpg" class="wide high" id="x1y2" />
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The one I clicked opens the popup, but clicking cancel no longer closes the popup, even when I've clicked `#x1y1pop`.

Comment: That can be solved in a similar way. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Well. That did it. I wish I knew more about this, but tutorials don't give you the same knowledge as does experience. I'll figure it out. Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to help. For more info on element reversal with jQuery see: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/